# why the data-target is not working in bootstrap if I use php to generate the id?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to list some of the speakers details. Let say for example my code is the following:

```
    <?php

        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM  `Invited_Speakers_auto`   ORDER BY `Last_Name` ASC;");
        foreach ( $result as $print)   { ?>


<div class="DemoBS2" > 


  <!-- Toogle Buttons -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="toggle-btn"
  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $print->Unique_Id;?>" >Click to Toogle</button>

    <div id="<?php echo $print->Unique_Id;?>" class="collapse in">
      <p>If you don't like something, <b>change it</b>. 
      If you can't change it, change your <b>attitude</b>.</p></div>


</div>


 <?php } ?>
```

It gives my only the toggle buttons but its not working as such.

What is the mistake. [click here to see the error](http://iclaa2017.com/test-template/).

thanks in advance.

### Edit:

When I run the above query and php code, I get the following for the first entry.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#17ICLAA501
">Click to Toogle</button>

    <div id="17ICLAA501
" class="collapse in">
      <p>If you don't like something, <b>change it</b>. 
      If you can't change it, change your <b>attitude</b>.</p></div>


</div>
```

I dont know, why the space is coming after the $Unique_Id in both data-target and id.

Is that the thing does not allow the boostrap not to work?

### Note:

I have checked that unique id is not repeating anywhere.

Comment: $print->Unique_Id; needs to be investigated, so please provide us with a example of the class $print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the data-target use jQuery to select the item. Spaces here and new lines is not a part of the ID. But the attribute ID contains spaces and new line as part of the ID. So data-target looks after ID 17ICLAA501 but it doesn't exist as ID equals 17ICLAA501\n

In your new example you forgot to truncate your id for spaces and new lines (http://iclaa2017.com/test-template/):

This is your html result:

```
<div class="DemoBS2"> 
  <!-- Toogle Buttons -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#17ICLAA501
">Click to Toogle</button>

    <div id="17ICLAA501
" class="collapse in">
      <p>If you don't like something, <b>change it</b>. 
      If you can't change it, change your <b>attitude</b>.</p></div>
</div>
```

That means that you don't have a clean ID.

The result should be:

```
<div class="DemoBS2"> 
  <!-- Toogle Buttons -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#17ICLAA501">Click to Toogle</button>

   <div id="17ICLAA501" class="collapse in">
      <p>If you don't like something, <b>change it</b>. 
      If you can't change it, change your <b>attitude</b>.</p></div>
</div>
```

I will recommend you too use chrome developer tool, where you easily can live edit and see your result. Please vote my answers as well ;)

try to replace $print->Unique_Id with preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $print->Unique_Id);

So your code should be like this:

```
<?php

        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM  `Invited_Speakers_auto`   ORDER BY `Last_Name` ASC;");
        foreach ( $result as $print)   { ?>


<div class="DemoBS2" > 


  <!-- Toogle Buttons -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="toggle-btn"
  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $print->Unique_Id);?>" >Click to Toogle</button>

    <div id="<?php echo preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $print->Unique_Id);?>" class="collapse in">
      <p>If you don't like something, <b>change it</b>. 
      If you can't change it, change your <b>attitude</b>.</p></div>


</div>


<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yeah..You are correct. I have checked the space correction using google developer tools and its working fine after removing the space. But since, I am new to php, kindly correct my codes and give me explicit answer.

Comment: I am not doing php by my self. But you can do like preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $print->Unique_Id); I have updated the answer with your code. So please approve the answer.

Comment: thank you @Dasma for your answer. It works fine. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

By investigating your online example, I can see that the Unique_Id doesn't get set to the DOM element. So that data-target get set too # and id empty string. You need to investigate $print->Unique_Id which return empty string. It works when you set data-target and id.

```
<?php echo $print->Unique_Id;?> gives a empty string in your example page.
```

The html result of your working example:

```
<div class="DemoBS2">
  <!-- Toogle Buttons -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggle-example">Click to Toogle</button>

    <div id="toggle-example" class="collapse in">
      <p>If you don't like something, <b>change it</b>. 
      If you can't change it, change your <b>attitude</b>.</p></div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggle-example1">Click to Toogle</button>

    <div id="toggle-example1" class="collapse in">
      <p>If you don't like something, <b>change it</b>. 
      If you can't change it, change your <b>attitude</b>.</p></div>
</div>
```

The html result of your NOT working example:

```
<div class="DemoBS2"> 


  <!-- Toogle Buttons -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#">Click to Toogle</button>

    <div id="" class="collapse in">
      <p>If you don't like something, <b>change it</b>. 
      If you can't change it, change your <b>attitude</b>.</p></div>


</div>
```

Maybe try this:

```
<?php $uuid = uniqid(); ?>
<div class="DemoBS2">
  <!-- Toogle Buttons -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="toggle-btn"
  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $uuid;?>">Click to Toogle</button>

    <div id="<?php echo $uuid;?>" class="collapse in">
      <p>If you don't like something, <b>change it</b>. 
      If you can't change it, change your <b>attitude</b>.</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for ur kind reply and I am sorry that mistakenly, I have placed 2 div classes in my source just before the query which caused the empty string. I have updated my code in source and in the question. Kindly help me out to rectify this